# Fill column with ones based on the count of another column python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

Below is the sample dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime(2011, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2012, 1, 1)
index = pd.date_range(start, end)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Trade Days": 0}, index=index)

df.iloc[0,:]=2
df.iloc[5,:]=3
```

As you notice, 'Trade Days' column has 2 on '2011-01-01' and has 3 on '2011-01-06'. I want to create another column filled with 1s based on count value in 'Trade Days' column. Sample output column is as follows:-

```
df['open position']=0
df.iloc[0:2,1]=1
df.iloc[5:8,1]=1
```

I can only think of for loop based filling. Is there an efficient way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create groups by test non `0` values by not equal [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and compare first values of groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for greater by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html), last convert output boolean mask to integers for `True, False` to `1, 0` mapping:

```
g = df['Trade Days'].ne(0).cumsum()

grouped = df.groupby(g)['Trade Days']
df['new'] = grouped.transform('first').gt(grouped.cumcount()).astype(int)
print(df.head(10))

            Trade Days  open position  new
2011-01-01           2              1    1
2011-01-02           0              1    1
2011-01-03           0              0    0
2011-01-04           0              0    0
2011-01-05           0              0    0
2011-01-06           3              1    1
2011-01-07           0              1    1
2011-01-08           0              1    1
2011-01-09           0              0    0
2011-01-10           0              0    0
```